# In C++, is there a way to lock the object itself?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I have a stl map which I would like to be synchronized across several threads. Currently I have...

Function A (Modifies map)

```
void Modify(std::string value)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&map_mutex);

    my_map[value] = value;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&map_mutex);
}
```

Function B (Reads map)

```
std::string Read(std::string key)
{
    std::string value;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&map_mutex);

    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = my_map.find(key);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&map_mutex);

    if(it != my_map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        return "DNE";
    }
}
```

This is synchronized across all threads, due to the mutex. However, I have to lock the mutex in Function B even though it is not modifying the map at all. Is there a way to lock the my_map object itself in function A, and not lock it in function B while keeping thread synchronization. This way, all instances/calls of Function B continue to run freely, so long as Function A is not being run?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for a reader/writer lock. I know that boost has one (it's called `shared_lock`).

Comment: Pthreads seem to already have it too: `pthread_rwlock_t`

Comment: "*Function B … is not modifying the map at all*". [Wanna bet?](http://ideone.com/7jnQE) `operator[]` can modify its map.

Comment: @RobᵩI was going to point this out too, I had a nasty bug recently caused by exactly this. - use*find*instead if you don't want to add the missing item

Comment: @hamstergene does the pthread_rw_lock (when it has to write) wait for the reading to be done?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes does the shared_lock(when it has to write) wait for the reading to be done?

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes, thank you, I forgot, I will change the code asap

Comment: Well, the only other option for operator[] would be to throw an exception so it's actually logical it modifies the map.

Comment: @Joshua yes, that's the point. At any one time you have either: no thread holding the lock; one thread holding the lock for writing; one or more threads holding the lock for reading. I suppose the mentioned `pthread_rwlock_t` works the same.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It seems that the pthread implementation is/can be slower, I will start out with the boost implementation and profile it to see for sure. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Using the `find` iterator in `Read` outside the lock is bad news I would think. An over-write of the returned element can invalidate this iterator resulting in a horrific hard-to-find bug. Also your locks as shown here are not exception-safe, if you stick with POSIX use guards as with `boost::shared_lock`. Any good reason to not pass in the params as `const std::string&` ?

Comment: While i dont want to question the decisions made by OP i want to point to the Poco Framework which has a very easy to use and though complete multithreading support. http://pocoproject.org/slides/130-Threads.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't just want to lock the container, you also want to lock accesses into the container i.e. any iterators or pointers into it. You need to move those accesses into the locked region of the code.

```
std::string Read(std::string key)
{
    std::string value = "DNE";

    pthread_mutex_lock(&map_mutex);

    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = my_map.find(key);
    if(it != my_map.end())
    {
        value = it->second;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&map_mutex);

    return value;
}
```

There's really no practical way to do this from inside the object itself.

Comment: Note that this code is not exception safe. If `find` throws an exception, the mutex will be left locked ... likely forever. (That's probably fine for a map whose key is a `std::string`, but it can be a problem for a map that uses a type whose comparison operators can throw.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I didn't get into that because as you say `std::string` is unlikely to throw (except for std::bad_alloc), and other answers had already covered the solutions to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I have not compiled or tested any of this, but I've done similar things in the past.

Step one would be to control the mutex with class, as such:

```
class Lock {
    public:
        Lock(Mutex& mutex) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        }
        ~Lock(Mutex& mutex) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
        }
};
```

This saves you from all sorts of issues, for instance, if your map throws an exception.

Then your modify becomes:

```
void Modify(std::string value)
{
    Lock(map_mutex);    

    my_map[value] = value;
}
```

Create a reference counted lock class:

```
class RefCntLock {
    private:
        static int count;
        static Lock* lock;

    public:
        RefCountLock(Mutex& mutex) {

             // probably want to check that the mutex matches prior instances.
             if( !lock ) {
                  lock = new Lock(mutex);
                  count++;
             }
        }
        ~RefCountLock() {
             --count;
             if( count == 0 ) {
                 delete lock;
                 lock = NULL;
             }
        }
};
```

(Note: it'd be easy to generalize this to deal with multiple mutexes.)

In your `read`, use the RefCntLock class:

```
std::string Read(std::string key)
{
    {
        RefCntLock(&map_mutex);

        std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = my_map.find(key);
    }

    if(it != my_map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        return "DNE";
    }
}
```

This means that each write gets a lock but all reads share a lock.

Comment: I don't understand how the `RefCntLock` works. It seems like if one read has occured, then the constructor won't relock or increment? You should increment anyway. Also the name of the constructor and destructor is wrong. Only adding for others to more quickly clear their confusion. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming C++17 standard, you can use `std::shared_mutex` and `std::shared_lock` to allow multiple readers exclusive read access, and `std::unique_lock` to implement exclusive write access.

```
std::shared_mutex map_lock;

void Modify(std::string value)
{
    auto write_lock = std::unique_lock(map_lock);
    my_map[value] = value;
}

std::string Read(std::string key)
{    
    auto read_lock = std::shared_lock(map_lock);
    auto it = my_map.find(key);
    return (it != my_map.end()) ? it->second : "DNE";    
}
```